# How to reuse and reinitialize c++ discrete_distribution in class?

Tags: c++, random, boost, boost-random

I am writing a discrete distribution random number generator in a c++ class. The requirements are:

1. I don't want to create a discrete_distribution object each time I use it. I know distribution object is lightweight, but my weight array is so long that the cost is still too high. Also, I need to use the distribution object in different functions in this class.
2. I need to change the distribution (weight array) from time to time
3. I don't know the exact distribution (weight array) when the class is constructed

Currently I have two solutions, after initialize random number engine with `random_device rd; mt19937 engine;` in class and `engine(rd())` in initialize list.

One is to create the discrete_distribution object with `discrete_distribution<> *d=new discrete_distribution<>(weight_array,weight_array+weight_array_size)` and store the pointer in the class. Each time I call (*d)(engine) to generate a random number, and I just need to delete the distribution and make a new one to update the weight array.

Another way is to define `discrete_distribution<> d` in class and update weight array with `d=discrete_distribution<>(weight_array,weight_array+weight_array_size)`, so that we can generate random number with `d(engine)` and don't need to worry about pointers.

But it seems that both ways are not classical way to use c++ objects. Are they wrong? Are there any drawbacks to write code this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another way is to define `discrete_distribution<> d` in class and update weight array with `d=discrete_distribution<>(weight_array,weight_array+weight_array_size)`, so that we can generate random number with `d(engine)` and don't need to worry about pointers.

This is perfectly fine, common C++ style to deal with object instances.

In fact many types do not have modifier members because they are assignable.

In this case you could, however use the `params()` member to change the weights:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e6e8302c63b7078)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace br = boost::random;

struct X {
    using Weight = double;
    br::mt19937                            engine { br::random_device{}() };
    br::discrete_distribution<int, Weight> dist   { {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2} };

    void sample() {
        for (auto i : {1,2,3,4})
            std::cout << "#" << i << ":" << dist(engine) << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void show_probabilities() {
        boost::copy(dist.param().probabilities(), std::ostream_iterator<Weight>(std::cout << "probabilities: ", " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void reprogram(std::initializer_list<Weight> probabilities) {
        dist.param(probabilities);
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    x.show_probabilities();
    x.sample();

    x.reprogram({0.01, 0.99});

    x.show_probabilities();
    x.sample();
}
```

Printing something like

```
probabilities: 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 
#1:1 #2:2 #3:0 #4:4 
probabilities: 0.01 0.99 
#1:1 #2:1 #3:1 #4:1
```